# Vista skin look and feel

Tags: java, windows-vista, themes

Is there anywhere on the web free vista look and feel theme pack for java?

Answer (score 2):

I'm guessing that what you want is to use the system look and feel regardless on whatever platform your application is started. This can be done with

```
UIManager.setLookAndFeel( UIManager.getSystemLookAndFeelClassName() );
```

on the main() method (you have to handle possible exceptions of course ;-).

As I don't have a vista installation here I can't check whether the jvm natively supports the vista laf...

edit: Seems to be possible with the above statement. See this thread in the java forums:

http://forums.sun.com/thread.jspa?threadID=5287193&tstart=345

Answer (score 0):

If you use SWT it has a native vista look and feel built in.  However, if you are using swing I honestly do not know.

Answer (score 0):

Using Java6u13 on Vista shows a Windows LookAndFeel that is pretty decent.  Its as free as Java is.

Sun has a tutorial on LookAndFeel usage [here](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/tutorial/uiswing/lookandfeel/plaf.html) and if you want to play with the [SwingSet demo](http://java.sun.com/products/jfc/jws/SwingSet2.jnlp), it shows you the System LookAndFeel and lets you change it.  Then you can get an idea of what the LookAndFeel looks like.  Calling

```
UIManager.setLookAndFeel(UIManager.getSystemLookAndFeelClassName());
```

as [dhiller](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/119696/vista-skin-lf#120198) suggests, will set the look and feel based on your system. If you wanted to see what the Vista look and feel looks like, you'll need Vista though.

Another option is to use [Substance](https://substance.dev.java.net/) or [Nimbus](https://nimbus.dev.java.net/) if you want something different from the Metal look and feel.  Substance is a separate look and feel collection and Nimbus is available as of the 6u10 release.